# Fetching a Blob Audio File to Openai Whisper-1 api

Tags: blob, cloudflare, openai-api, openai-gym, openai-whisper

Im trying to fetch a audio file to openai whisper-1 from a Cloudflare Worker.

When I console.log my audio file that reaches the Worker i get Blob { size: 588542, type: 'audio/x-m4a' }.

How do i fetch the refered audio file to openai whisper-1? Following the documentation [here](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/speech-to-text/quickstart?lang=curl) below is what I tried:

```
export async function onRequest(context) {
   // await checkAuthorization(context)
   const formData = await context.request.formData();
   const audioFile = formData.get('audioFile');

   try {
      const url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions';
      const requestOptions = {
         'method': 'POST',
         'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${context.env.apikey}`,
         },
         'body': JSON.stringify({
            'model': 'whisper-1',
            'temperature': 1,
            'language': 'eng',
            'audioFile': audioFile,
         }),
      };
      const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
      const res = await response.json();
      const responseOptions = {
         'headers': {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
         },
      };
      return new Response(JSON.stringify(res), responseOptions);
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error("Error ", { cause: error })
   }
}
```

And I get the error:

```
  error: {
    message: 'Could not parse multipart form',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    param: null,
    code: null
  }
```